# C++ Arduino 1.6 on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: arduino, embedded

I'm working on Arduino, and wanna build a small toy piano. For practice I create my own class called map.

```
#ifndef Map_h
#define Map_h

#include "Arduino.h"
template <class Key, class Value> class Map
{
public:
    Map();
    ~Map();
    void add(Key key, Value value);
    Value find(Key key);
private:
    Key *keys;
    Value *values;
    int size;
    bool resize();
};

#endif
```

In main I just call it normally:

```
Map<char, int> *name_to_freq = new Map<char, int>();
name_to_freq->add('c', 262);
```

But I got some error when compile.

```
ccQwtG4w.ltrans0.ltrans.o*: In function main
ccQwtG4w.ltrans0.o*: (.text.startup+0x354): undefined reference to Map<char, int>::Map()
ccQwtG4w.ltrans0.o*: (.text.startup+0x3de): undefined reference to Map<char, int>::add(char, int)
```

Definition in .cpp file:

Does any one see this before and know how to solve it?

```
template <typename Key, typename Value>
Map<Key, Value>::Map()
{
    keys = new Key[defaultArraySize];
    values = new Value[defaultArraySize];
    size = defaultArraySize;
}

template <typename Key, typename Value>
void Map< Key,  Value>::add(Key key, Value value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (!keys[i]) 
        {
            keys[i] = key;
            values[i] = value; 
            if (i >= size/2)
            {
                while (!resize());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: where is the definition of your Map() and add()?

Comment: One second....Adding

Comment: are the definition is on the source file(cpp file)?

Comment: Yes. Visual Studio auto generated .h and .cpp files for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your template definition to header file.

when working in template class, when you instantiate it the compiler will create a class with the template argument you fed to it, in order to do that the compiler should access the definitions of your functions, but it cannot access them because they are in the source file.

**Way 1:**

```
template <class Key, class Value> class Map
{
public:
    Map();
    ~Map();
    void add(Key key, Value value);
    Value find(Key key);
private:
    Key *keys;
    Value *values;
    int size;
    bool resize();
};

template <typename Key, typename Value>
Map<Key, Value>::Map()
{
    keys = new Key[defaultArraySize];
    values = new Value[defaultArraySize];
    size = defaultArraySize;
}

template <typename Key, typename Value>
void Map< Key,  Value>::add(Key key, Value value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (!keys[i]) 
        {
            keys[i] = key;
            values[i] = value; 
            if (i >= size/2)
            {
                while (!resize());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

or you can directly define them in the class (**Way 2**)

```
template <class Key, class Value> class Map
{
public:
    Map()
    {
    }
    ~Map();
    void add(Key key, Value value)
    {
    }
    Value find(Key key)
    {
    }
private:
    Key *keys;
    Value *values;
    int size;
    bool resize();
};
```